# Heredoc string and TCPDF to build dynamic PDF

Tags: php, tcpdf, heredoc

I am attempting to build a PDF based on the information in a database that I have. I am getting a 500 internal server error when I do. The code that is throwing the error is:

```
<?php
include('db.php');

    $pdfArray = array();

    $top = '<h1>Med One Equipment List</h1>
            <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Manufacturer</td>
                    <td>Model</td>
                    <td>Description</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
        ';
        array_push($pdfArray, $top);

    while($rowAll = mssql_fetch_array($allResult)) {
        $html = '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$rowAll["Manufacturer"].'</td>
            <td>'.$rowAll["Model"].'</td>
            <td>'.$rowAll["Make"].'</td>
        <tr>';
        array_push($pdfArray, $html);
    }

    $bottom = '</tbody>
                </table>';

    array_push($pdfArray, $bottom);

    $table = implode(" ", $pdfArray);

    $html =  <<<EOF 
    {$table} 
    EOF;
?>
```

I am just including this file when I build my PDF with TCPDF. Let me know if I need to include some of the TCPDF code. I can't for the life of my figure out why it won't work. My guess is that I'm using herdoc incorrectly.

Comment: A 500 server error when coding in PHP means that your script is triggering an error. You should really configure your dev environment in such a way that you can **view** all error messages. Ask for help about that if you need it, but please stop guessing :)

Comment: I have done this to display errors, but it never does. http://www.cs.trincoll.edu/hfoss/wiki/How_to_display_errors_in_PHP

Comment: In the TCPDF class, which this is included into. That shouldn't be there anyway. I pasted old code. Let me revise.

Comment: In which line are you getting an error

Comment: The error comes in the: `$html =  <<<EOF 
{$table} 
EOF;`

Comment: What happens if you just use `$html = <<<EOF(new_line)$table(new_line)EOF;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the raw formatting of your code, it looks like

```
$html =  <<<EOF
{$table} 
EOF;
```

is indented with a tab.  If that is the case in your real code, the problem is that the end of a heredoc must be the first thing on a line.  If it is indented at all, it will break.  So if your code is indented, it will need to look something like this:

```
if($example_block){
    $html =  <<<EOF
    {$table} 
EOF;

    {other indented code}
}
```

P.S. The observations about the indenting with a tab I mentioned above were from before the question was edited, but wither way, if it is indented with a tab or spaces, it will break.  Also, Kyle is is correct in stating that the opening identifier must also be immediately followed by a new line.

Comment: Awesome. I had no idea that indenting and spaces were so important. Kyle's answer also helped.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy and pasted your code.  The error is coming from a space that is located just after your `<<<EOF` line.

You have `$html = <<<EOF(space)`.

Should be `$html = <<<EOF`.